# How do I check if a specific jquery-easing method is defined?

Tags: jquery, jquery-easing

I have a jQuery plugin. One of the options is what easing method to use for animations. I want to be able to check if the easing method is defined, before I go on and call the `$.animate(...)` function with the specified easing method. Like so:

```
var easingMethod = option.easing;
if (!IsDefined(easingMethod)) easingMethod = 'linear';
```

What would be `IsDefined()` function?

I could do `if (typeof(easingMethod)==undefined)` but `typeof(easingMethod)==='string'`. I'm thinking more along the lines of

```
function isDefined(s) {
   // If a method named 's' is defined, return true, else false
}
```

And I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
function isDefined(s) {
  return $.easing.hasOwnProperty(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. I should probably ready more about `hasOwnProperty(s)`.